# Making dotted letters shorter

Tags: fontsize

I'd like to manipulate how the dotted letters look in the text.
You can see an example below:
[image: dotted letter]

Without changing the font or letter itself, is there a way to do this?

Comment: the best way would be to change the font. If not you could replace each i by a scalable image of a modified i, however this would break any kerns between adjacent letters and the i.

Comment: The target "i" here would be one specific "i" in the text. Not all of them. In this case replacing it with an image may work but do you think it's a practical solution?

Comment: yes for a single letter it seems perfectly reasonable, just make sure that your image is pdf not a bitmap like png.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would appreciate it if you could give a small example of how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

This clips the bottom bit of the letter and the top bit of the letter and then over-prints them adjusting the height of the top to match the `m`. The exact amounts to shift will vary depending on the font used.

Here I have included the top of the base along with the dot so the gap is the same the same as the original letter, you could just take the dot but then you would lose serifs at the top of the base. Not an issue here as a sans serif font is used.

If the vertical part of the i is not constant thickness in the font used, you will see the join...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}
\def\myi{%
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt {.7\height}}{i}%
\llap{\raisebox{.1em}{\clipbox{0pt {.5\height} 0pt  0pt}{i}}}%
}
\Huge\sffamily

Aim

A\myi m

A\i m

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This scales the `i`  and superimposes a clipped `i` so the distance from the stem to the dot is reduced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}

\newcommand{\myi}{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\clipbox{0pt {\depth} 0pt 0pt}{\raisebox{\dimexpr1ex-\height}{i}}}%
  \resizebox{\width}{1ex}{i}%
  }

\begin{document}
\Huge\sffamily

Aim A\myi m

\end{document}
```

[image]